# Use l3build to build and package a font package

Tags: fonts, package-writing, ctan, l3build

I would like to use `l3build` to build and package a support package for a TrueType/OpenType font.

## File Layout

```
truetype/MyFont.ttf
build.lua
my-font-package.dtx
my-font-package.ins
```

### File Contents

#### `build.lua`

```lua
-- Identify the bundle and module
bundle = ""
module = "my-font-package"

-- Typeset only the .tex files
typesetfile = {"*.tex"}

-- Sources files
sourcefiles =
  {
    "my-font-package.dtx",
    "my-font-package.ins",
    "truetype/MyFont.ttf",
  }

installfiles = {"*.sty", "*.ttf"}

-- Use LuaLaTeX for compiling
typesetexe = "lualatex"
```

#### `my-font-package.dtx`

```tex
% \iffalse meta-comment
%
% My font package
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{l3doc}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \title{^^A
%   \pkg{my-font-package}^^A
% }
%
% \author{^^A
%   Stephan Lukasczyk^^A
% }
%
% \begin{documentation}
%
% \end{documentation}
%
% \clearpage
%
% \begin{implementation}
%
% Start the \pkg{DocStrip} guards.
%    \begin{macrocode}
%<*package>
%    \end{macrocode}
% Identify the package and give the overall version information.
%    \begin{macrocode}
\ProvidesExplPackage {my-font-package} {2023-09-08} {0.1}
  {My font package}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
%</package>
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \end{implementation}
%
% \PrintIndex
```

#### `my-font-package.ins`

```tex
\iffalse meta-comment

My font package

\fi

\input docstrip.tex
\askforoverwritefalse

\preamble

My font package

\endpreamble
\nopostamble

\keepsilent

\generate
  {%
    \file{my-font-package.sty}
      {%
        \from{my-font-package.dtx}{package}
      }
  }

\endbatchfile
```

#### `truetype/MyFont.ttf`

The content of `truetype/MyFont.ttf` does not matter, only the file and folder need to exist, thus, executing `mkdir truetype; touch truetype/MyFont.ttf` should be sufficient to create it on a Linux/macOS machine.

## Problem/Question

When I run `l3build` (e.g. using `l3build ctan`) it produces nice results for the package and documentation inside the `build` folder, as one would expect.  However, the `MyFont.ttf` is not part of that tree.

My question thus is, how can I configure `l3build` in a way that it includes the `*.ttf` file into the build and into the appropriate location such that I could send the package to CTAN or install it locally using `l3build install`?

Edit: While the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695480/14622) by @Niranjan provides me a way to include the `*.ttf` file into the build result, I'd prefer to have it in some TDS compliant way, i.e., the files should result in some `fonts` directory (maybe `fonts/truetype/my-font-package/*.ttf`, if I understand TDS correctly).  `l3build install` should, for example, also install them in the correct location.

Comment: `my-font-package.dtx` has an error. As it is, the MWE returns an error. Hopefully the error isn't there in the actual .dtx.

Comment: I did not encounter an error when I ran the MWE on my machine. Besides, I'll take care that the actual .dtx works correctly, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Out of the box, `l3build` knows a few common TDS locations. You can add more using the `tdslocations` table, for example

```lua
tdslocations =
  {
    "fonts/truetype/my-font-package/*.ttf"
  }
```

or if you want to keep it more generic:

```lua
tdslocations =
  {
    "fonts/truetype/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.ttf"
  }
```

---

The standard settings for `sourcefiles` and `installfiles` do not contain `*.ttf`, so that or some variant thereof (to deal with the additional directory) will also be needed here.

Comment: Do I have to put the *.ttf files then at a specific location? I've tried next to `build.lua`, in `truetype/`, and in `fonts/truetype/my-font-package/`, but nothing makes them go into the `build` directory. I've only added the line you've suggested to my `build.lua` and removed the `ttf` entries from its `sourcesfiles` and `installfiles` tables.

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk I assumed that you'd spotted that `sourcesfiles` is a typo - the variable is called `sourcefiles` (I fixed in  your question and assumed your real files didn't have that issue)

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk `*.ttf` needs to stay in `sourcefiles` and `installfiles` as again this is not on the standard list

Comment: Yes, I should not have removed the `ttf`s from `sourcefiles` and `installfiles`. Thanks for pointing this out, and thanks for fixing the typo.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `docfiles` parameter. You can add the following:

```lua
docfiles     = { "truetype/*.ttf" }
```

This will correctly add the .ttf file to the zip.

Comment: While I agree that this puts the ttf files into the zip, I doubt that their target folder is now correct. For me, they are put into the `doc` folder, although I would (from the TeX Directory Structure) assume that they should live somewhere in `fonts`. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk Oh, I wasn't aware you are using TDS. Sorry, I don't know about that structure much, so won't be able to talk about it. I usually go with the auto-created zip.

Comment: If that works for the CTAN maintainers, I could live with this, too. Although I assume that they would have some manual work then. For now, your solution works, so thank you for that. However, I'd like to leave the question open; maybe, somebody knows for a TDS compliant solution.

Comment: @StephanLukasczyk Sure, you can keep it open. That's not a problem, but I would suggest adding your specific requirement in the question itself :) Also, as far as CTAN maintainers are concerned, `l3build ctan` is developed _specifically_ for the convenience of CTAN maintainers. I think the old TDS requirement has gone now [citation needed].

Comment: I agree on `l3build`'s purpose regarding CTAN packaging. However, `l3build install` does not install the fonts at all :(