Installing fonts with l3build install
I am having the following directory-structure:
├── build.lua
└── CharisSIL-Regular.ttf

With the following build.lua:
module              = "bar"
tdslocations        = {
  "fonts/truetype/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.ttf"
}
sourcefiles         = { "*.ttf" }
installfiles        = sourcefiles

the font gets installed at the correct location, but my intended directory structure is this:
├── build.lua
└── support
    └── CharisSIL-Regular.ttf

I tried the following build.lua without success:
module              = "bar"
tdslocations        = {
  "fonts/truetype/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.ttf"
}
sourcefiles         = { "support/*.ttf" }
installfiles        = sourcefiles

What's wrong here? I don't want to clutter my working directory with files other than dtx, ins and lua, but I want this font to be installed. This is related to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695488/. Joseph has some comments there regarding sourcefiles and installfiles which (I am guessing) worked for the OP, but I think I am missing something.

This question can also be found at: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=8067

are you packaging this for upload to ctan? or are you doing this for local installation? note that you are missing vendor in the tds location.

you probably need e.g. installfiles = {"*.ttf", "*.sty"} or whatever and sourcefiles = {"support/*.ttf", "*.dtx", "*.ins"} or what-have-you. you're overwriting the defaults, so you have to include a complete list. omit the subdirectories for installfiles. they aren't being copied from your source directory. if you are packaging for ctan, you also need to specify non-standard binary files e.g. binaryfiles = {"*.ttf", "*.pdf"}.

https://codeberg.org/cfr/nfssext/src/branch/main/fontscripts/fntbuild-vars.lua may help, but note that there are a lot of additional variables here which won't apply, so you'll have to ignore those.

[I wonder what .zz files are for.]

@cfr This is not going to be a CTAN package, for that I would prefer uploading fonts as a separate package, but imagine I have some files required in a CTAN package, let's say images/PDF files to be embedded, I would love to know the procedure and method for doing that.

What's a vendor?

Thanks a lot!!! Adding the setup you suggested works. I will keep in mind the binaryfiles variable.

@Niranjan Please post your answer, so that it'll use to some one in future

@GowriSaro I will wait for cfr to post it as it is her answer technically.

@Niranjan you should be able to add images/PDF for embedding to the installfiles, I think. you only need to add them to binaryfiles for the .zip.

@cfr thanks a lot for all the assistance.

installfiles shouldn't include the sub-directory as the files aren't copied from the source directory. So you probably want something like this:
installfiles = {"*.ttf", "*.sty"}
sourcefiles  = {"*.dtx", "*.ins", "support/*.ttf"}

Note that you need to include all file types in the lists, as you are overwriting the defaults. If you are packaging for CTAN, you should also include the .ttf in binaryfiles so it is marked as binary in the .zip.
The canonical TDS location for a .ttf includes a vendor:
vendor = vendor or "public"
tdslocations = {
    "fonts/afm/" .. vendor .. "/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.afm",
    "fonts/enc/dvips/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.enc",
    "fonts/map/dvips/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.map",
    "fonts/opentype/" .. vendor .. "/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.otf",
    "fonts/tfm/" .. vendor .. "/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.tfm",
    "fonts/truetype/" .. vendor .. "/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.ttf",
    "fonts/type1/" .. vendor .. "/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.pfb",
    "fonts/type1/" .. vendor .. "/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.pfm",
    "fonts/vf/" .. vendor .. "/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.vf",
    "source/fonts/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.etx",
    "source/fonts/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.mtx",
    "source/fonts/" .. module .. "/" .. "*-drv.tex",
    "source/fonts/" .. module .. "/" .. "*-map.tex",
    "tex/latex/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.fd",
    "tex/latex/" .. module .. "/" .. "*.sty"
}


I understood everything, but what's a vendor? I will add it nevertheless in my packages, but I am curious to know what it actually is. Couldn't find anything in the documentation of l3build.

@Niranjan If you look in the fonts directory of your TeX install, you will find things like fonts/truetype/intel/clearsans/ intel is the vendor. but public is also treated as a vendor for all those fonts where there's no established vendor directory. traditional font names indicate the vendor if they use the 'Berry' naming scheme e.g. in fonts/type1/adobe/courier/pcrb8a.pfb: p means Adobe, cr is Courier, b is bold and 8a is the encoding.

@Niranjan but for some reason, not all sub-directories of fonts/ use a vendor sub-directory. so e.g. there's no vendor in the hierarchy of directories for .map files or .encs. I have no idea why it was done this way, though.

@Niranjan and, no, l3build is essentially oblivious to fonts ....

I will keep in mind the vendor variable too. This is some really interesting information. Is there any resource where I can read more about it? A TUGBoat paper maybe? You should write one if there isn't any :)

@Niranjan try texdoc fontname?
